# Some folders are not pushed on github

Tags: github

I would like to push a project on github. However I cannot push all the projects. It still some subfolders that are not uploaded. What can I do ?

Comment: Are these folders part of any commit?

Answer (score 0):

Only files that are tracked and committed will be 'uploaded' when you push to the remote server.

1. Check if the folders are added. You can do a `git status`, and it will list them as untracked if they haven't been added.
2. Add them. `git add [file/folder name]`
3. Commit them. `git commit -a -m "Adds [some file]"`
4. Push to your remote. `git push -u origin master`

Comment: You should mention also `.gitignore` - Verify that these folders are not there

Comment: emote: Permission to tdenewiler/node_example.git denied to raouiyounes.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tdenewiler/node_example.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Answer (score 0):

Make sure those folders are not ignored. Pick one file in them and type:

```
git check-ignore -v path/to/ignored/folder/afile
```

That will print any `.gitignore` file/rule which might apply and explain why said folder was not added/committed when you dod a `git add .`/`git commit`.